# How to create a SAFEARRAY in Windows JScript?

Tags: javascript, winapi, safearray

I want to create a SAFEARRAY of type byte in Windows JScript.
Can you give me some example code or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacky but `stripting.dictionary::items` is returned as a safe array so in some circumstances (ADSI queries) the following works, however YMMV significantly in trying this with binary data.

```
function getSafeArray(jsArr) {
    var dict = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");
    for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; i++)
    dict.add(i, jsArr[i]);
    return dict.Items();
}

//to a safe array
var safearr = getSafeArray([11,22,33]);

//back to a js array
var jsArr = new VBArray(safearr).toArray();

log(jsArr[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

JScript doesn't allow you to create safe arrays, you would probably need to write an ActiveXObject to handle this for you.