# How do I pass an array of integers from classic asp to a c# COM object?

Tags: c#, com, asp-classic

I'm trying to pass an array of integers from Classic ASP to a DLL created in C#.

I have the following C# method:

```
public int passIntArray(object arr)
{
    int[] ia = (int[])arr;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.Length; i++)
        sum += ia[i];

    return sum;
}
```

I've tried a number of ways to convert arr to an int[], but not having any success.  My asp code is:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var x = Server.CreateObject("dllTest.test");
Response.Write(x.passIntArray(arr));
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Int32[]'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it or tell me it can't be done?

Using the code on this very useful page http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/12/20/type-name-system-comobject/ I have managed to find out that the type of the passed parameter is "JScriptTypeInfo" if that's of any use.

If I add:

```
foreach (object m in arr.GetType().GetMembers())
    // output m
```

I get the following output:

```
System.Object GetLifetimeService()
System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(System.Type)
System.String ToString()
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
Int32 GetHashCode()
System.Type GetType()
```

Comment: As int[] is marshalled by Com Interop as a SAFEARRAY, this is essentially a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910538/how-to-create-a-safearray-in-windows-jscript

Comment: If it's a duplicate, then I don't understand it because I don't know how to take the answer from that to make my code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [SO item I suggested was a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910538/how-to-create-a-safearray-in-windows-jscript), you would change your ASP code thus:

```
function getSafeArray(jsArr) 
{
  var dict = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");     
  for (var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; i++)     
    dict.add(i, jsArr[i]);     
  return dict.Items(); 
} 
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
var x = Server.CreateObject("dllTest.test"); 
Response.Write(x.passIntArray(getSafeArray(arr)));
```

You should also change your C# method signature to:

```
public int passIntArray(object[] arr) // EDITED: 17-Sept
```

or

```
public int passIntArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_I4)]  int[] arr)
```

The point is that you are not really trying to go from JavaScript to C#, you are going from JavaScript to COM: you can only interface the C# DLL at all because it is ComVisible and is registered in the COM registry with a ProgID which `Server.CreateObject` can look up. With the signature change, your DLL's COM-exposed interface will expect to receive an unmanaged [SAFEARRAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the script code above is a way to get JavaScript to provide one, using the COM Scripting.Dictionary as a sort of custom marshaler.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, but it doesn't work.  I get error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch

on the Response.Write line.  I have split the line into parts, and it is the x.passIntArray bit that causes the error.  Getting the safearray into a variable works fine.

Comment: Try the amended C# method signature as per my edit above, and see if that calls the C# method successfully. You'll then have to cast the elements to `int` inside the method. (Alternatively you may be able to help the marshaler do the right thing by attributing your C# method argument with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_I4)]`)

Comment: Where do I put the attribute - I have put it just before the method and it seems to be happy there, but it doesn't like VT_I4 - does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, that should be `public int passIntArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_I4)]  int[] arr)`. Note you are attributing the argument, not the method.

Comment: That don't work either, but I give up, I'm gonna give it to you as it works without the marshalling, though annoyingly, I have to cast each element to an int