# How to access array elements of SAFEARRAY from MS JScript?

Tags: com, jscript, safearray

A COM object lives in a DLL. Its IDL looks roughly like this:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(51EB4046-221E-45EF-BD63-0D31B163647C),
    oleautomation,
    dual,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IOne2OneNode : IDispatch
{
    // ...
    [propget, id(2), helpstring("property Vector")] HRESULT Vector([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
};
```

The DLL fills in `*pVal` with a `SAFEARRAY` of `VT_R8` (using `COleSafeArray`).

I want to access the array elements from a JScript script that is executed with cscript.exe.

I tried `node.Vector[1]`, but it reports

```
TestIDispatch.wsf(115, 2) runtime error in Microsoft JScript: 'node.Vector' is Null or not an object
```

(modulo German to English translation errors).
Also, `typeof node.Vector` reports `unknown`.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910730/6868543), I tried

```
var vec = new VBArray(node.Vector).toArray();
```

but it reports `runtime error in Microsoft JScript: VBArray expected`.

How can I access the array elements from JScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JScript can only process `SAFEARRAY`s with element type `VT_VARIANT`. Any other element type is incompatible.

It is correct to convert the returned array using

```
var vec = new VBArray(node.Vector).toArray();
```

but the COM server must create an array of `VARIANT`s, i.e., type code `VT_VARIANT`; `VT_R8` will end up in a type mismatch error.

Found in the responses to [this post](http://computer-programming-forum.com/58-jscript/54ba4963ae1b8602.htm).